# Jquery to replace a Href tag if the Original destination link is invalid?

Tags: html, jquery, web

I am seeking a way (If possible) to replace the href attribute on a tags if the destination of the original link is broken or a 404 page.

Not sure if Jquery is the correct way to do it, but i would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This might be possible, yet also very intensive. Is this a static page? If it has access to Server Side scripting, this could use cURL to check the URL before presenting it. Otherwise you need to write a function that makes a request for the URL, tests it, and modifies items. The caveat is that it might consume a lot of resources for the browser. There is also a lot of Cross Site protection in the browser, so the request might fail for a lot of reasons that not related to the state of the URL.

Comment: We have access to server-side scripting. The idea is that we can replace broken URLs by any means possible through uploading a single script to a template that will auto run on every single page. Hopfully that helps!

Comment: Replace them with what?

Comment: @BraydendeKoning need a better example.